# Finding only path through directed graph which visits all nodes exactly once

Tags: graph

Suppose I have a directed graph that only has **exactly one path** which visits **all** the nodes **exactly once**.

Since there is only one possible path, a start (no arrows pointing to it) and end node (no arrows pointing from it) - marked in red - can be easily identified. Thereafter, I can use brute force to determine the path.

I'd like to learn a better way of doing this, assuming the conditions given in paragraph 1 are always true for the graph.

[image: Example of a graph with only one possible path, visiting all nodes exactly once.]

Comment: Your second sentence does not necessarily follow from the first. What is your current brute force method? DFS until you have a path of length `N-1` would seem to be about as efficient as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should do a breadth-first search, start at your starting node, add all neighbours to a Queue, look at the first item from the Queue, add all its neighbours to the Queue, repeat.

https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search